# How to receive file pointer from kernel space by giving file pointer from user space

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems

From user space
`FILE* fd1 = fopen("./log/log1.txt","r"); 
syscall(338, fd1);`

I tried
`SYSCALL_DEFINE1(get_class, struct file *, fd)` 
But didn’t work! 
How to add a tag to `fd1` in kernel system?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this?  It doesn't make any sense. A `FILE *` refers to a *user-space* structure used to buffer IO.  Passing such a pointer to the kernel will do what?  Having the address of a user-space structure inside the kernel is pretty useless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an "XY problem" in the sense that you are using the wrong approach to attempt whatever it is you are trying to do.  `edit` the question to clarify what you are trying to *achieve* and it may be possible to re-open a modified version and obtain an answer actually useful.